# Difficulty getting script loaded in footer by CodeIgniter to execute

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-2

I am loading a js file in the footer of a CodeIgniter app. I am using this technique

```
    //Controller
    $data['scripts_to_load'] = ['prospects/add'];

    $this->load->view('system/template', $data);

    // View
    <?php foreach($scripts_to_load as $script) { ?>
            <script type='text/javascript' src = '<?= base_url();?>js/<?= $script;?>.js'>
    <?php } ?>

    // JS
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('going');
    //});
```

The script shows on the page but does not execute (regardless of whether the document ready wrapper is included). Other javascript included in the view files and header works as expected.

Comment: `$data['scripts_to_load']` is not array and you are trying to use `foreach`

Comment: I think it is an array in php5? It is outputting the full correct path on the rendered page..

Comment: $data['scripts_to_load'] = ['prospects/add'];.  ['prospects/add']-this is not array. Or if its some array varialbe it need to be prefixed with $.

Comment: So it to clarify it does iterate over the for-each correctly, put perhaps you are correct. I'm no longer at the office so can't be sure. You're saying that $thing = ['one','two'] is not valid php? Or if it is valid it is not typecast as an array? Thanks for your input, I write a lot of js so definitely missed that !

Comment: If the script is loaded in the page as you have mentioned, it might be an error in the script itself that prevents it from executing. Just check if there are any console logs in browser.

Comment: You are saving your array to $data['scripts_to_load'] and then iterating a different variable $scripts_to_load.. that second var doesn't exist. You need to use one or the other.. but in both places